# How to turn a list of integers into a string of numbers?

Tags: python, nltk

I'd like to turn

```
[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
```

into

```
['1','2','3','4','5','4','3','2','1']
```

in preparation of doing `FreqDist`.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert to string?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to convert intergers to individual strings, so that i can freqdist and see the frequency of each number

Comment: `>>> map(str,[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1])
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']`

Comment: Beat you to it Kasra ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use the built-in map function when casting each item in the list:

```
newList = map(str, oldList)
```

Comment: No that didn't work. Somehow the result was a list inside a list, which chained all integers into one long string.

Comment: @Auborey can you add more code and explain to your question?

Comment: Did you pass in the list as described? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: idk how to freqdist mylistofnum which is created by extracting the values from another dictionary

Comment: Change your `mylistofnum = [results.values()]` line to `mylistofnum = results.values()` then apply the method suggested by @MalikBrahimi

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple list comprehension

```
>>> myar=[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
>>> [str(i) for i in myar]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

Comment: A list comprehension is very inefficient with simple operations like casting.

Comment: not sure why that's not working either. maybe becos those are not really integers but values so that won't work